polars cast multiple columns to categorical
    import polars as pl

    X = pl.from_pandas(pd.read_csv("../resources/adult_test_df.csv", index_col=False))
    cols = [
        "workclass",
        "education",
        "marital-status",
        "occupation",
        "relationship",
        "race",
        "native-country",
    ]
    X[cols] = X[cols].astype("category")

This syntax belongs to Pandas. How to make this work for Polars?

Try df = df.with_columns(pl.col(cols).cast(pl.Categorical)).
